# Generalizing a new operator over many types

Tags: f#, typeclass, functor, generic-programming, f#-unquote

I am using Unquote and did not see any approximate comprison.
So I decided to write one.

```
let inline (=~=) x y = abs x-y <  1.E-10
```

However the operator is not mapped onto, say Lists

```
let test  = [1;2] =~= [1;2]  //---> error
```

Is it possible to declare this operator to flow like `(=)` ?

Or would it require to define a new traits like 'StructuralEquality-ishness"?

Is it better to define a new operator with, say, http://code.google.com/p/fsharp-typeclasses/ ?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot edit the List type - it is already defined. You could check (with the `:?`) if the type is a list, and if so use your own definition - but there are no type classes in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Unquote, but regarding the approximate function/operator I'm not sure if there is a way to implement it with structural comparison.

If you want to do it "by hand", using a technique (or trick) similar to the one used for the F# Typeclasses Project, here is an example:

```
type Approximate = Approximate with
    static member inline ($) (Approximate, x:^n       ) = fun (y:^n) -> float (abs (x-y)) <  1.E-10
    static member inline ($) (Approximate, x:list< ^n>) = 
        fun (y:list< ^n>) -> 
            x.Length = y.Length && (List.zip x y |> List.forall ( fun (a,b) -> (Approximate $ a) b))
// More overloads
let inline (=~=) x y = (Approximate $ x) y
```

Comment: Very fine. for my edification, does your library contains bits that would already more or less fit this ?

Comment: That project is just a Demo project. The goal was to show the technique, not to use it in production (though I don't see any problem with this). You don't need to link it just to implement this, none of the Typeclasses defined there will help in this particular case, but if you are interested in that technique is a good reference.

Answer (score 3):

(I haven't used Unquote so this may not be applicable.)

Take a look at the signature of your function

```
'a -> 'b -> bool (requires member ( - ) and member Abs)
```

`List` doesn't support either of those operators. Yes, your function is generic but the constraints preclude its use with lists.

`(=)`, on the other hand, has no constraints, meaning it can be used with any type. If your function can be rewritten to remove the constraints then it can be used similarly (but I don't see how that's possible considering the use of `-` and `abs`—how do you expect a `list` to behave with those operators?).

Comment: I don't expect this operator to work as it is, but a modified version of it. the question is how to I lift this operator in the most generic way. the resulting operator on list would require its elements to satisfy the contraints you mention, and yield a list of the results produced by the application of the original operator to each elements of both list, for instance

Comment: @nicolas: Good point, but equality is a pretty weak constraint, considering every type but those decorated with `[<NoEquality>]` satisfy it.